# Proof Verification: C closed, convex, symmetric in Banach space X and $\cup_{n \in N \setminus 0} n.C= X$ then $B_\epsilon(0) \in C $.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

I have an outline of the proof of this which I've expanded (correctly or otherwise) below, **I'd appreciate feedback on it**. (I think that C has to be closed in order to assert that $\cup_{n \in N \setminus 0} n.C= X $, but I'm not sure about that)

$\cup_{n \in N \setminus 0} n.C= X $, and from the Baire category theorem, X is not the countable union of nowhere dense sets, so that at least one of the n.C must contain some open set.
Since open sets are preserved under scaling, then C too must contain an open set, and therefore within it some open ball $B_\epsilon(x) \in C $.

Any vector $z \in B_\epsilon(-x) \subset X$ satisfies $||z – (-x)||  = ||-z - x|| < \epsilon$. So $-z \in B_\epsilon(x) \subset C$.

Since C is symmetric then $z = -(-z) \in C$ and therefore $B_\epsilon(-x) \subset C$.

If $w \in B_\epsilon(0)$  then $||w|| < \epsilon $

Let $z_1 = w + x$, so that $z_1 - x = w$, then $||z_1 – x|| < \epsilon$ and so $z_1 \in  B_\epsilon(x)$. Similarly, $z_2 \in  B_\epsilon(-x)$

But $w = z_1 + (z_2 – z_1)/2$ and so by the convexity of $C$, $w \in C$ and therefore $B_\epsilon(0) \subset C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to invoke Baire you have to assume the closedness of $C$. Otherwise your proof is fine.

Comment: Many thanks. If I understand correctly (now), then by Baire $X$ is not meagre as it contains itself, a non-empty ($0 \in X$) open set ($X$ and $\emptyset$ are always open [and closed]). By definition of meagre, some $n.C$ is not nowhere dense, consequently $int(cl(n.C)$ is not empty. So $C$ needs to be closed to move from $int(cl(n.C) \ne \emptyset $ to  $int(n.C) \ne \emptyset $ - yes ?

Comment: It depends on your notion of "Baire", but you are correct. I am used to the formulation "if the countable union of closed sets has an interior point, one of the closed sets has an interior point".

Comment: Thanks again. I had four equivalent definitions, now I have five.

 1. for every countable collection of open dense sets their intersection is dense.

 2. The complements of all meagre sets (i.e. the countable union of nowhere dense sets) are dense

 3. Every meagre set has an empty interior.

 4. Every none-empty open set (and in particular B itself) is non meagre.

 5. Whenever the union of countably many closed subsets of B has an interior point, then one of the closed subsets must have an interior point.